# kendo-datepicker format date onChange($event) in Angular

Tags: angular, date-formatting, kendo-datepicker

We are using Angular 6, .NET mvc framework. Based on date selection, I need to pass it to a function and populate a dropdown. But I am not retrieving the date in correct format. Here is the html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Select Report Date:</label>
    <kendo-datepicker [(value)]="value" 
          (valueChange)="onChange($event)">
    </kendo-datepicker>
</div>
```

Here is ts file.

```
 public lobs: Array<VTO> = [];
 public value: Date = new Date();

 public onChange(value: Date): void {
    console.log('change', value);
    this._vtos.getLOBs(value)
      .subscribe(data => this.lobs = data,
    error => this.errorMsg = error);
 }
```

value on Console.log is

```
change Thu May 10 2018 06:59:26 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

whereas I need it 'MM/dd/yyyy' format, so that I get 05/10/2018. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
public onChange(value: Date): void {
    console.log('change', this.getFormattedDate(value));
    this._vtos.getLOBs(value)
      .subscribe(data => this.lobs = data,
    error => this.errorMsg = error);
 }

getFormattedDate(date) {
    let year = date.getFullYear();

    let month = (1 + date.getMonth()).toString();
    month = month.length > 1 ? month : '0' + month;

    let day = date.getDate().toString();
    day = day.length > 1 ? day : '0' + day;

    return month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
}
```

Comment: If did return the formatted date, however, what will be the typescript version of this code?

Answer (score 1):

```
 //use format input like below
<kendo-datepicker
                  [format]="'MM/dd/yyyy'"
                  [value]="value"
              ></kendo-datepicker>
```